# How to suggest Date/Time when a user is typing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

This happens in Apple's reminders app, where whenever you start typing something that somewhat resembles a date, it starts predicting what date or time you're typing; even if you type in words like:

```
eleventh feb  =>  11/02/20 (suggested).
```

How can I implement this using JavaScript in my react native app?

Does it require AI/ML or can it be done using something simpler?

Comment: You can check as they type, and if it contains a slash, there's one indicator.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too, but I don’t think that is very efficient and scalable